# Objective-C for loop to Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, for-loop

What is the nicest and cleanest way to translate this Objective-C for-loop to Swift 3? What is best practice? Should I use a while loop?

```
NSInteger pageHeight = 792;
NSInteger pageWidth = 612;

for (int page=0; pageHeight * page < scrollView.frame.size.height; page++) {
    // execute some code
}
```

I tried to work with something like this

```
for i in pageHeight * i < scrollView.frame.size.height {
    // execute some code
}
```

but I cannot reuse the variable i since it cannot be used. Compiler gives the error: unresolved identifier 'i'.

EDIT: one of the reasons I asked the question was because I wanted to specifically know what the best practice is and to avoid creating an additional variable before the loop code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't change any of the loop-related variables inside the loop, you can do it this way:

```
let pageHeight: Int = 792
let pageWidth: Int = 612
let pageCount = Int(scrollView.frame.size.height) / pageHeight
for page in 0..<pageCount {
}
```

Comment: so is there no way without creating an additional variable? and thank you for the answer!

Comment: Not if you wish to use a `for` loop. But keep in mind that this is more efficient than your original code since it does the math just once instead of for each loop iteration.

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi: You *can* get rid of the additional variable: `for page in 0 ..< Int(scrollView.frame.size.height)) / pageHeight {...}` but I don't see any advantage.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a while loop:

```
let pageHeight = 792
let pageWidth = 612
var page = 0
while pageHeight * page < Int(scrollView.frame.size.height) {
    // execute some code
    page += 1
}
```

Comment: You can't compare `Int` to `CGFloat`. You need a cast in there.

Comment: so is there no way without creating an additional variable? and thank you for the answer!

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi There are no more variables in this answer than in your original OC code.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, you are right, my bad. Is there any real advantage of this solution over the other answer with the for loop solution?

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi This answer and my answer both work. Both do allow you (if needed) to change the value of `page` inside the loop (though you need to change `for page` to `for var page` in my answer). The `for` loop does have one slight advantage - you can't accidentally change the value of `page` inside the loop (unless you add the `var`). But otherwise it's a personal choice in this case.

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi Oh yeah - one other slight advantage to the `for` loop in my answer - it's more efficient. The math is only done once, not on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As another option, here's a recursive/functional option:

```
func setupPages(maxHeight: CGFloat, pageHeight: CGFloat, pageNumber: Int = 0) {
    guard (pageHeight * CGFloat(pageNumber)) < maxHeight else {
        return
    }
    // do what you need to do
    setupPages(maxHeight: maxHeight, pageHeight: pageHeight, pageNumber: pageNumber + 1)
}
```

Then in your code you can just simple call:

```
setupPages(maxHeight: scrollView.frame.height, pageHeight: CGFloat(pageWidth))
```